# Remote Desktop and Aero in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, aero

From what I've heard and read so far I should be able to enjoy Aero over a remote desktop connection. Both computers here run Windows 7 Professional but enabling Desktop composition doesn't do anything. Searching around only told me that it should work out of the box on Windows 7 while Server 2k8 R2 needs a little more work to get it working.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this chart - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart

Footnote 38: http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/08/21/remote-desktop-connection-7-for-windows-7-windows-xp-windows-vista.aspx#9902608

> The Experience features are available when you connect to Windows 7 from Ws2008 R2 as well. However you get the full set of features only when you connect to Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate editions. When you connect to Windows 7 Professional features such as multimedia redirection, bi-directional audio, multiple monitor etc will not be available.

Comment: Ah, dang. So it would have worked in the beta and RC *sigh*.

Comment: I made an edit to specifically point out the proper URL.  The chart overall provides the "Aero glass remoting[37][38]" but I figured the direct link is more informational.

Comment: I meant the first link of the references, sorry. Wikipedia told me enough already. But reference 37 only babbles about features (which look cool) and how to set up Server 2k8 R2 but doesn't go into detail on the required Win 7 SKU. That's what I meant. Thepost you now quoted was actually more informative :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a hack to make it work look here http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/p/79427/422442.aspx#422442