# Windows 7 Aero Glass Remoting on professional

Tags: windows-7, aero

Are there any registry edits or hacks to enable aero **glass** remoting on Windows 7 professional it seems to only be available on ultimate and enterprise.

I am talking about aero glass transparency effects not the aero theme over a remote desktop connection. If you remote to an ultimate machine the glass effects are enabled but if you do it to a professional one they are not as it currently stands.

**Please don't close this question** there was a previous one closed from another user. But the closers didn't understand the question properly. All comments and answers were either about enabling transparency locally or enabling the aero interface over RDP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Desktop and Aero in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/78709/remote-desktop-and-aero-in-windows-7)